# Find last element of an array with a certain property in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am looping through a nested array in smarty, and each element has a status of 'active' or 'inactive'. How can I detect the last element in the array that is set to active?

example code:

```
{foreach from=$steps item=step name=step}
 {if $step.status == 'active' && ????? }

 {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the array indexed numerically or by key? If numeric i think the `item` argument in your loop is the index so you could use that in your if. if its not then youll have to call `count` to get the total number of items and then manually increment. or you could use `array_values`  to transform the keys to numeric before starting your loop. Not really sure how to do any of that in Smarty though.

Answer (score 1):

Just use step parameter for foreach statement and use predefined variable $smarty.foreach.*NAME*.last

```
{foreach from=$steps item=step name=step_foreach}
    {if $step.status=="active" && $smarty.foreach.step_foreach.last}
        last step is active
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something, that goes outside template logic and should be done in script.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what "smarty" is, but the usual way to do this is to just keep a reference to the last element found; e.g.,

```
{foreach from=$steps item=step name=step}
    {if $step.status=="active" && ...}
        $last_step = $step
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Then, at the end of your loop, `$last_step` will be a reference to the last active `$step`.  It you don't want the actual element, just its index, then save the index instead.

Comment: Smarty is a templating engine that supposedly has a purpose despite the fact that PHP itself is just a glorified templating engine (and i say this with a huge amount of love for PHP) :-)